# Difference in subfolders by comparing 2 folders

Tags: vb.net, powershell

For my work I need to compare 2 network folders. I need to output the names of the subfolders that are missing to a .txt file.

Example:

```
Folder1
  -Sub1
  -Sub2
  -Sub4

Folder2
  -Sub1
  -Sub3
  -Sub4
```

Output:

```
Missing Sub2, Sub3
```

How I can do this?

Comment: take a look at Directory.GetDirectories: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx . You can compare and extract the missing directories and output them to a file using StreamWriter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The examples in both links should help you achieve what you need

Comment: Have you tried anything? We will not do the complete coding for you. Look at the [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class and [Directory.GetDirectories()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325(v=vs.110).aspx) method, read about [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb763068.aspx), especially [Intersection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) and come back if you have a concrete problem.

Comment: If this is a one time operation, do yourself a favor and buy a Beyond Compare license *(not affiliated btw)*.

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the list of folder or comparing two list?

Answer (score 0):

Below I have written code that grabs the subdirectories of each folder. It then loops through these directories to gain just the names of the folders. It finds the missing subdirectories from each folder and collects them into 2 lists.

I suspect there is an easier way to do this than the way I have here, but it works.

```
    'Declare lists for each folders
    Dim folder1SubDirectories As New List(Of String)
    Dim folder1SubNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim folder2SubDirectories As New List(Of String)
    Dim folder2SubNames As New List(Of String)


    'Declare folders locations as variables
    Dim folder1Location As String = "Folder1 path location"
    Dim folder2Location As String = "Folder2 path location"

    'add the subdirectories of each folder into the appropriate list
    folder1SubDirectories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(folder1Location))

    'add the name of the subdirectory to a new list
    For Each subfolder In folder1SubDirectories
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(subfolder)
        folder1SubNames.Add(dirInfo.Name)
    Next

    'add the subdirectories of each folder into the appropriate list
    folder2SubDirectories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(folder2Location))

    'add the names of the subddirectories into a new list
    For Each subfolder In folder2SubDirectories
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(subfolder)
        folder2SubNames.Add(dirInfo.Name)
    Next

    'The below LINQ finds the missing subdirectories and puts them in them in the list
    Dim missingSubs = folder1SubNames.Union(folder2SubNames).Except(folder1SubNames.Intersect(folder2SubNames)).ToList()

    'Now you can do whatever you need to do with the missing subdirectories
    For Each missingSub In missingSubs
        Console.WriteLine(missingSub)
    Next


    Console.ReadLine()
```